# Need help making a POST request in R using FIXML and ROAuth

Tags: xml, r, oauth, roauth

I'm trying to connect to a trading API and I've been successful making GET requests, but when I try to make a POST request I keep getting error messages from the API.  I've searched the internet and forums for an answer, but all similar questions have ended unresolved.

Here's the R script I'm using:

```
# Call the required packages
library(ROAuth)
library(RJSONIO)
library(XML)

# Set your application keys
cKey <- 'xxxx'
cSecret <- 'xxxx'
oKey <- 'xxxx'
oSecret <- 'xxxx'

# Set the API endpoint
tkURL <- "https://api.tradeking.com/v1/accounts/xxxxxxxx/orders/preview.xml"

# Create the OAuth connection - this is straight from the ROAuth documentation on CRAN 
credentials <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = cKey,
                                consumerSecret = cSecret,
                                oauthKey = oKey,
                                oauthSecret = oSecret,
                                needsVerifier = FALSE,
                                signMethod='HMAC')

# Update the connection so the handshake is TRUE
credentials$handshakeComplete <- TRUE

# Create FIXML
doc <- newXMLDoc()
root <- newXMLNode('FIXML', namespaceDefinitions = 'http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2',
                       newXMLNode('Order', attrs=c(TmInForce='0', Typ='1', Side='1', Acct='xxxxxxxx'),
                               newXMLNode('Instrmt', attrs=c(SecTyp='CS', Sym='FAS')), 
                               newXMLNode('OrdQty', attrs=c(Qty='1'))), doc=doc)
newFIXML = saveXML(doc, encoding='UTF-8')
newFIXML

# Post order
response <- credentials$OAuthRequest(tkURL, method = "POST", newFIXML)
response
```

When I run this, I get this response:

```
"<response id=\"-3491729f:14e4f104ddc:7f50\">\n\t
<type>Error</type>\n\t
<name>ScriptFailure</name>\n\t
<description></description>\n\t
<path>/v1/accounts/xxxxxxxx/orders/preview.xml</path>\n</response>"
attr(,"Content-Type")
                            charset 
"application/xml"           "UTF-8"
```

I talked with the API guy and he gave these suggestions, but said that he couldn't help with the R code:

> I am not familiar with R so I'm probably not going to be much help on
>   the code part. As for the response id, it seems that the headers were
>   incorrectly sent in the body of the request along with the fixml.
>   Also, the fixml seems to be encoded, it should not be. This is more
>   like xml or text and the content type should reflect that in your
>   request so that it does not try to encode it. Instead of
>   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, you should try
>   Content-Type: text/xml. Here (pasted below) is what we got from your
>   request:

```
Headers:
    Host:api.tradeking.com Content-Length:668 Accept:*/* Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded 


    Body:
    =%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3CFIXML%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fixprotocol.org%2FFIXML-5-0-SP2%22%3E%0A%20%20%3COrder%20TmInForce%3D%220%22%20Typ%3D%221%22%20Side%3D%221%22%20Acct%3D%22xxxxxxxx%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CInstrmt%20SecTyp%3D%22CS%22%20Sym%3D%22FAS%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3COrdQty%20Qty%3D%221%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FOrder%3E%0A%3C%2FFIXML%3E%0A&oauth_consumer_key=xxxx&oauth_nonce=xxxx &oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1435846001&oauth_token=xxxx&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=xxxx%2xxxx%3D
```

How would I go about fixing this in the code?

Comment: Btw, I am using ROAuth 0.9.2 as specified by the API documentation

Comment: this is mostly a shot in the dark, but try this: `credentials$OAuthRequest(tkURL, method = "POST", postfields=newFIXML, httpheader=list('Content-Type'='text/html'))`. Also, I don't know about the encoding part

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the FIXML code after the URL like this:

```
tkURL <- "https://api.tradeking.com/v1/accounts/******/orders/preview.json"
xsfixml <- "<FIXML xmlns=\"http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2\"> <Order TmInForce=\"0\" Typ=\"2\" Side=\"1\" Px=\"8.5\" Acct=\"******\"> <Instrmt SecTyp=\"CS\" Sym=\"UNG\"/>     <OrdQty Qty=\"1\"/>  </Order> </FIXML>"
tkURLfixml <- paste(tkURL, xsfixml)
response <- credentials$OAuthRequest(tkURLfixml, method="POST",)
```

Or did you find a better solution?